# Proper way to transform a point cloud

Tags: pcl, tf2, pcl-ros, transform, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using V-REP to simulate a vehicle with a Velodyne. To simulate the behavior of the real Velodyne, I transform at each simulation pass the captured points to the /odom frame. This is to gather 360º data and correct the delay between samples due to the car velocity (this is what I asked in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/239849/how-is-tf-data-handled-by-velodyne_driver/)).

Now, other members of my team, need the point cloud to be given relative to the velodyne frame (base_laser), so I just need to transform the point cloud relative to /odom to the desired target frame. My tf tree is /odom->/base_link->/base_laser and is working fine. I use Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo.

The best solution I found was using the pcl_ros package and I tried doing

```
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 buffer_local;
tf::TransformListener listener;

pcl_ros::transformPointCloud("/base_laser",_buffer, buffer_local, listener);
_pubVelodyne.publish(buffer_local);
```

being **_buffer** the previous pointcloud relative to /odom.

I am getting the following error:

> [ERROR] [1475751606.660104363]: "base_laser" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.

It looks like transformPointCloud calls the lookupTransform function but is unable to find the "base_laser" frame. My tf tree is correct (I've checked it with rosrun tf view_frames) and if instead of transforming it to "base_laser" I transform it to "/odom" (itself), I get the original pointcloud without errors, as expected.

Where can be the error? Is the use of the TransformListener right? My pointcloud uses the timestamp of ROS, so it should be right. Another option would be using the transformPointCloud funtion with the transform directly retrieved from tf by me.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1:**

I was using the TransformListener just after creating it, that's why I got that error. Now I create a listener as a class member and I get another error:

> [ERROR] [1475759993.562920093]: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1475759993.562353881 but the latest data is at time 1475759993.468326569, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [base_laser]

I understand I get this error because transformPointCloud wants to use a later transform, so I should use waitForTransform before calling transformPointCloud, right?

So, if I want to use the latest transform available, I would have to manually retrieve it using

```
listener.lookupTransform("/odom", "/base_laser", ros::Time(0), transform);
```

and then use

```
transformPointCloud(original_PC, transformed_PC, transform_matrix)
```

(after converting the StampedTransform to a Transform object).

**UPDATE 2:**

Simply use this [pcl_ros::transformPointCloud](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/pcl_ros/html/namespacepcl__ros.html#a34090d5c8739e1a31749ccf0fd807f91) definition.

**UPDATE 3:**

The previous only works for PointCloud data. For PointCloud2 the available definitions of pcl_ros::transformPointCloud are [these](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pcl_ros/html/namespacepcl__ros.html#a29cf585a248dc53517834f4c5a1c4d69).

In order to get the latest available transform, it must be done as suggested in my first Update of this question.

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245111/proper-way-to-transform-a-point-cloud/) by [OMC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27334/omc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2016-10-06

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `TransformListener` needs time to store some transforms so that interpolation can be done. I usually try to create transform listeners as member variables of my class so that they are persistent during runtime. If you are declaring `listener` as a local variable in a function and then immediately trying to use it then you will get those types of errors.

**Edit:**
If you want to use the latest transform I suggest using the [pcl_ros::transformPointCloud](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/pcl_ros/html/namespacepcl__ros.html#aad1ce4ad90ab784aae6158419ad54d5f) that accepts a `target_frame` and a `tf::TransformListener` as opposed to manually converting transforms yourself.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2016-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OMC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27334/omc/) on 2016-10-06**:
Thank you, you are right. I have edited my original question, I can't mark it as solved yet because I still get an error.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2016-10-06**:
For the updated question you can take a look at [tf and Time](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20(C%2B%2B) tutorial. Have you tried adding `waitForTransform`? The tutorial addresses the specific error you see in your update. Did you get any new errors?

**Comment by [OMC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27334/omc/) on 2016-10-06**:
Yes, I tried it and everything works fine with an appropriate delay. But in my case, I think it would be more accurate to work with the latest available transform. Is the only way of doing that by manually retrieving it, as I suggest in my updated question?

**Comment by [OMC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27334/omc/) on 2016-10-06**:
Using the  pcl_ros::transformPointCloud is what I was originally doing, and according to the errors I got, It doesn't use the latest transform. I have to wait for a new one, otherwise, I'll get the error "Lookup would require extrapolation at time [...]".

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2016-10-06**:
If you really want to use the latest transform then you will have to do some conversions. However, the function I linked to uses the timestamp of the original point cloud get the transform. To me that seems like a better time to use than the most recent time else you might get rotation errors.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2016-10-06**:
Note that there is also a [pcl_ros::transformPointCloud](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/pcl_ros/html/transforms_8hpp_source.html#l00160) that accepts a `target_frame`, a `tf::listener`, *and* a `target_time` that might work better for what you are trying to do.

**Comment by [OMC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27334/omc/) on 2016-10-06**:
I have just realised of that definition of the function (my bad!!!). That will very likely do what I intend to.
Thank you for your time.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2016-10-06**:
I'm glad it's working for you.

**Comment by [OMC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27334/omc/) on 2016-10-06**:
I spoke too soon... that definition is for PointCloud data types, not for PointCloud2. Only 3 definitions of pcl_ros::transformPointCloud take PC2 as arguments: [link](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pcl_ros/html/namespacepcl__ros.html#a29cf585a248dc53517834f4c5a1c4d69). None uses ros::Time as input.